# PHP not finding a existing key in array

Tags: php, web

I'm making something for me and my friends
So, i have a array with symbols. It looks like

```
$array = [
   "0" => "000a "
]
```

I put there `"♧" => "100a "` but it is not finding the **♧** and any other special characters in the array. Whats the reason for that and how to fix it?

```
<?php 
    $default = [
        "0" => "000a ",
        "1" => "000b ",
        "2" => "000c ",
        "3" => "000d ",
        "4" => "000e ",
        "5" => "000f ",
        "6" => "000g ",
        "7" => "000h ",
        "8" => "000i ",
        "9" => "000j ",
        "a" => "001a ",
        "A" => "002a ",
        "b" => "003a ",
        "B" => "004a ",
        "c" => "005a ",
        "C" => "006a ",
        "d" => "007a ",
        "D" => "008a ",
        "e" => "009a ",
        "E" => "010a ",
        "f" => "011a ",
        "F" => "012a ",
        "g" => "013a ",
        "G" => "014a ",
        "h" => "015a ",
        "H" => "016a ",
        "i" => "017a ",
        "I" => "018a ",
        "j" => "019a ",
        "J" => "020a ",
        "k" => "021a ",
        "K" => "022a ",
        "l" => "023a ",
        "L" => "024a ",
        "m" => "025a ",
        "M" => "026a ",
        "n" => "027a ",
        "N" => "028a ",
        "o" => "029a ",
        "O" => "030a ",
        "p" => "031a ",
        "P" => "032a ",
        "q" => "033a ",
        "Q" => "034a ",
        "r" => "035a ",
        "R" => "036a ",
        "s" => "037a ",
        "S" => "038a ",
        "t" => "039a ",
        "T" => "040a ",
        "u" => "041a ",
        "U" => "042a ",
        "v" => "043a ",
        "V" => "044a ",
        "w" => "045a ",
        "W" => "046a ",
        "x" => "047a ",
        "X" => "048a ",
        "y" => "049a ",
        "Y" => "050a ",
        "z" => "051a ",
        "Z" => "052a ",
        "!" => "053a ",
        "?" => "054a ",
        "," => "055a ",
        "." => "056a ",
        "_" => "057a ",
        "(" => "058a ",
        ")" => "059a ",
        "$" => "060a ",
        " " => "061a ",
        "/" => "062a ",
        "=" => "063a ",
        "#" => "064a ",
        "@" => "065a ",
        "%" => "066a ",
        "^" => "067a ",
        "&" => "068a ",
        "*" => "069a ",
        "-" => "070a ",
        "'" => "071a ",
        '"' => "072a ",
        ":" => "073a ",
        ";" => "074a ",
        "+" => "075a ",
        "×" => "076a ",
        "÷" => "077a ",
        "€" => "078a ",
        "£" => "079a ",
        "¥" => "080a ",
        "₩" => "081a ",
        "`" => "082a ",
        "~" => "083a ",
        "\\" => "084a ",
        "|" => "085a ",
        "<" => "086a ",
        ">" => "087a ",
        "{" => "088a ",
        "}" => "089a ",
        "[" => "090a ",
        "]" => "091a ",
        "▪︎" => "092a ",
        "○" => "093a ",
        "●" => "094a ",
        "□" => "095a ",
        "■" => "096a ",
        "♤" => "097a ",
        "♡" => "098a ",
        "◇" => "099a ",
        "♧" => "100a ",
        "☆" => "101a ",
        "⊙" => "102a ",
        "°" => "103a ",
        "•" => "104a ",
        "¤" => "105a ",
        "《" => "106a ",
        "》" => "107a ",
        "¡" => "108a ",
        "¿" => "109a ",
        "₽" => "110a ",
        "а" => "111a "
    ];

    $converted = '';
    $convertionType = $_GET["type"];
    foreach ( str_split($_GET['inputText']) as $val) {
        $converted = $converted . $default[$val];
    }
    echo $converted
    ?>
```

Comment: What makes you think it's ignoring them? Show how you're using the array.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Like showing the whole array?

Comment: Like when i try to use the **♧** it just doesn't outputs anything. The url of the website changes, but it doesn't shows anything on the website. With alphabetical characters (and others too) everything is good.

Comment: What do you mean "the url of the website changes"? What does an array have to do with the URL? Please show how you're using the array in the code.

Comment: The url has the ?inputText=♧ then. [This is the code](https://pastebin.com/raw/7sD11E2T)

Comment: @AndreasMelone You can not use special chars in the URL!

Comment: So, what should i do then? How should i do the thing then?

Comment: What do you see if you do `echo $_GET['inputText'];`?

Comment: you probably need to encode the special characters in the URL as `%hex`

Comment: You can do in reverse mode e.g: **?inputText=100a** and convert this URL argument in your code to display ♧

Comment: When i do ```echo $_GET['inputText']``` it works, but not when i'm doing that i need.

Comment: I found the problem. When i try to find the "♧" key in the array, it doesn't finds it.

Comment: Also, ♧ is returning �

Comment: The special chars not allowed in array key only in the value: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: How should i fix that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17858810/6087422

Comment: So, changing the string key in the array is a good idea, but its not realy what could work. Because i'm splitting the main string every 1 character and if i would put >1 character, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Relevant Link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10696067/2943403

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is convert your keys to utf8 so for example instead of "♡" you use "\xe2\x99\xa1"

Displaying a utf8 char is easy with json_decode so :

```
<?php
$chr = "\xe2\x99\xa1";
$chr2 = "\xe2\x99\xa4";
echo json_decode('"'.$chr.'"');
$array[$chr] = "Something";
$array[$chr2] = "SomeValue";
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array[$chr]);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array[$chr2]);
```

This will return this:

```
♡
Array
(
    [♡] => Something
    [♤] => SomeValue
)
Something
SomeValue
```

You should know all of the utf8 of your keys before hand. ... https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-encode < good online tool.