# Security concerns for using user provided data as array or session key

Tags: php

Are there any security concerns for using user provided data as an array or session key?  An non-defined index error is not a concern.  For instance, any dangers of doing the following?  If so, how is it mitigated?  Thanks

```
$var=$_SESSION['xyz'][$_GET['abc']];
```

EDIT.  The reason I ask...

User uploads a document.  It is stored in a tmp directory using a random name, and the filename is stored in a session using the random name as a key.  It "might" later be moved to a database and stored in a permanent location.

A link is provided to download the document which contains the random name.  Upon clicking, the filename is obtained using the random name as a key.

Comment: Non-defined index warnings should always be a concern. You should aim to have absolutely zero warnings in your code, so that when you get them unexpectedly, you can pin-point where the problem might be caused. The above is _safe_ to do, though, so long as there is no private information in the `$_SESSION['xyz']` array.

Comment: @halfer  Agree.  Warnings will not be displayed.

Comment: @user1032531: you may surpress warnings, but they are still happening. You should work to remove their cause, not disable them.

Comment: @crypticツ.  Good point.  Let me update my post on how it is being used.

Comment: @halfer.  With a properly generated random number, the odds of an error are about 1 in 10^40.  Script stopping on an error is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non filtered data is always a potential threat NEVER trust user provided data. That being said, you need to make sure user provided key is actually a valid key (no unexpected characters) to avoid code breaking characters. Then you could just use

`if(is_array($_SESSION['xyz']) && array_key_exists($key,$_SESSION['xyz']))`

to avoid the other gotchas mentioned above

Edit:

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696067/characters-allowed-in-php-array-keys) for valid indexes discussion

I corrected the function name as per your comment (sorry for that). As for the difference from isset() check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210935/difference-between-isset-and-array-key-exists).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks ghousseyn,  The application already knows that `$_SESSION['xyz']` is an array, and it is not based on user input.  I never used `key_exists()` before (by the way, it should be `array_key_exists()`), and is there any reason to use this over `isset()`?  Now the real big question.  How do I tell if there is any "code breaking characters" and how do I mitigate if there is?  As I originally stated, an error which stops the script is acceptable, but further breaches in security is not.  Thanks