# Convert Associative array from one form to other

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array like this..

```
array(26053) {
  [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["New York"]=>
      array(10) {
        ["state"]=>
        string(8) "New York"
        ["state_code"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["country_code"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["country"]=>
        string(24) "United States Of America"
        ["lat"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["long"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["city_id"]=>
        string(5) "70834"
        ["country_id"]=>
        string(4) "6532"
        ["country_iso"]=>
        string(2) "US"
        ["orignal_name"]=>
        string(1) ""
    }
}

  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Mexico, Ciudad De"]=>
    array(10) {
      ["state"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["state_code"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["country_code"]=>
      string(2) "52"
      ["country"]=>
      string(6) "Mexico"
      ["lat"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["long"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["city_id"]=>
      string(5) "72329"
      ["country_id"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["country_iso"]=>
      string(2) "MX"
      ["orignal_name"]=>
      string(1) ""
    }...
```

Like wise

For creating the above array I did this

```
$filename="city.dat";       
$lines=file($filename);                                              
$city_array = array();               

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $value) {
    $tmp_arry = array();                                           
    $parts = explode("\t", $value); 
    $tmp_arry[$parts[0]] = array();
    $tmp_arry[$parts[0]]['state'] = $parts[1];    
    $tmp_arry[$parts[0]]['orignal_name'] = $parts[11];    
    array_push($city_array, $tmp_arry);
}
```

Is there any way where I can make it to the below format because it would be easier for me to search in this format since the data is huge in city.data file

```
array(26053){
    ["New York"]=>.......
    ["Mexico"] => ...... }
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Try `$city_array = array_merge($city_array, $tmp_arry);` instead of `array_push($city_array, $tmp_arry);`

Comment: array_merge has a different functionality.!

Comment: What do you mean? It doesn't work?

Comment: it gave me empty array array (0) {}

Comment: Seems you just replaced `array_push()` with `array_merge()` instead of copying my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can totally do that (as long as city names are [valid keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10696097/1592398))

```
$filename="city.dat";       
$lines=file($filename);                                              
$city_array = array();               

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $value) {
    $parts = explode("\t", $value); 
    $city_array[$parts[0]]['state'] = $parts[1];    
    // other mapping goes here
    $city_array[$parts[0]]['orignal_name'] = $parts[11];   
}
```

another simpler approach is, having a mapping and [combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) the exploded values

```
$map = [
'city_name',
'state',
// .. 
'original_name' 
];

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $value) {
    $parts = explode("\t", $value); 
    $values = array_combine($map, $parts);
    $city_array[$parts[0]] = $values;
}
```

Hopefully this helps