# is it safe to use a email id as a key for array in php

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

I am trying to do the below in php

```
array(
  'email@domain.com' => 'something',
  ...
);
```

I did read that php accepts and number or valid string as key.

is it safe to have email id as key in the array as above ?
by safe I mean is possible that this could cause any kind of error or exception or problem when coding wit this

Note: 
I would be having several 100 items in this array is there something that I need to take care while I do this

Please let me know

Comment: Yes, so long as you fix that missing quote.

Comment: Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/10696067/2137833.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  @Sammitch thanks for pointing out the missing quote in the question

Comment: @Rick Good find. I'm going to flag this as a duplicate of that.

Comment: A string is a string. What do you think makes email addresses any different from any other string?

Comment: @RyanVincent I'm not sure what you're referring to. My question was directed at the OP, not a commenter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** If it can be a string in PHP, nowadays, it can safely be used as an associate array key.

**Long answer:** From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> The key can either be an integer or a string. The value can be of any
> type.
>
> Additionally the following key casts will occur:
>
> Strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type.
> E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8. On the other hand
> "08" will not be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer.
>
> Floats are
> also cast to integers, which means that the fractional part will be
> truncated. E.g. the key 8.7 will actually be stored under 8. Bools are
> cast to integers, too, i.e. the key true will actually be stored under
> 1 and the key false under 0.
>
> Null will be cast to the empty string,
> i.e. the key null will actually be stored under "".
>
> Arrays and objects
> can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal
> offset type.
>
> If multiple elements in the array declaration use the
> same key, only the last one will be used as all others are
> overwritten.

Comment: this almost looks safe, but consider if any string LEADING with number, will be converted to an int, and will trunkate the rest  "8mile@bigfen.com" will be stored as `8`.
So if you have any control over the email and you are SURE they are in a format "firstname.lastname..." it can work, but not for public emails.

Comment: @d.raev I just did a local test and the same email example you used (`8mile@bigfen.com`) with a leading number did not truncate down to `8`. Which seems in alignment with the the PHP manual casting rules that I linked. I'm not sure how you've come to your conclusion, can you care to elaborate?