# PHP performance, How to to get by key or by value in a big array?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, performance

I have a big array (10M of strings). I have to get value by key or by value many times.

To get by key, I use `isset` => O(1) => much faster.

To get by value, I use `in_array`or => O(n) => more slowly, because it does a linear search though the array until it finds the value.

In PHP, Is it possible to set key with more items and do optimize search on kthis key?

For example :

```
$bigArray = ((0, "s0") => true, 
             (1, "s1") => true, 
             (2, "s2") => false, 
              ...., 
             (1000000, "s1000000") => true);
$Test2 = get_optimize_function("s2", $bigArray); // Key = (2, "s2"), Value = false
$Test1 = get_optimize_function(1, $bigArray);    // Key = (1, "s1"), Value = true
```

Comment: so, your key is array?

Comment: No. In PHP array keys must be uniqe and it should be a string or an integer. I think something wrong with the design of the code. If it comes from database, then you need to narrow your results from the query. If not, then another alternative, if you flip the keys/values, so `true => [key1, key2, key3]`. Anyway, you sad, you need to search value sometimes, so it won't help you.

Comment: @lolka_bolka are you sure that php array keys should be strings?

Comment: @Lashane as I sent my comment, I immediatly removed that :) thx anyway, of course, it could be integer too.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696067/characters-allowed-in-php-array-keys

Comment: make key as '0|s0', '1|s1'....

Comment: @splash58, '0|s0', '1|s1' is a string, but how can i do an optimize search on '0', '1', 's0', 's1' ?

Comment: @LeMoussel I'm not sure why you ignored my question, lets repeat - is your key scalar value (as you explained) or array (as in yours example)?

Comment: @Lashane key is scalar value with a string and an integer.(0 to 1M)

Comment: @LeMoussel scalar value is either string or integer, you're describing array or struct or pair, which is not scalar value, with your current structure you cannot get boolean value from this array neither with integer nor string, for both your use cases you need to do full array scan

Comment: @Lashane But it's maybe  string, like splash58 say, with '0|s0', '1|s1', .. But I don't know how to do an optimize search on '0', '1', 's0', 's1'

Comment: @LeMoussel maybe you need 2 separate arrays, one where keys are integers, values are boolean, second where keys are string and values are boolean, then you will be able to perform both searches in avg O(1)

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to make additional array s0=>key0...

Comment: @Lashane I tested this, but it consume more memory. I can't do this.

Comment: @LeMoussel then I'd say - its impossible, either you have fast access (but spending more memory for special structures) or you have minimal memory footprint (with flat array) but slow access time, maybe you can provide more details of real problem, so we can find trade off