# alternative to in_array for unicode arrays

Tags: php, arrays, search, unicode

The in_array function is very slow for large arrays due to doing a linear search.

A faster alternative is to search the key of the array.

Thus

```
if (isset($array[$val]))
```

is much faster than

```
if (in_array($val,$array))
```

for large arrays. However using unicode as array keys will not work.

Is there an alternative way to do this for unicode without resorting to linear searches such as in_array or array_search or generating hashes like md5?

Comment: But `isset` is working with utf keys - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9ec34e6d0e17a0fc46d88942179c2024043b585d

Comment: @marv255 does not work with isset[$key]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use anything as key which can be converted into a string.

Compare: [Characters allowed in php array keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696067/characters-allowed-in-php-array-keys)

But nevertheless apparently some poeple have problems with special characters in their array-keys. I bet this may be the case if you use different encodings at the time you store the key and when you search for it. For example your keys come from a database using UTF-8, but when you search you have the key you search for hardcoded in a Iso-encoded PHP-script. This is just an example, there are dozens of scenarios like this. 
To ensure you always use the same encoding I would use [rawurlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php).

Comment: this works great. i'll wait to see if there is a better answer before accepting this